# Twitter module Oauth 'TwitterException' with message 'Unauthorized'

Tags: 7, social-network

When trying to authenticate a Twitter account using the Twitter and OAuth modules, I get the following error

> Could not obtain a valid token from the Twitter API. Please review the configuration.

I have since found that The following error is recorded in Watchdog

> exception 'TwitterException' with message 'Unauthorized' in /var/www/html/sitex/public/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.lib.php:151 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/sitex/public/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.lib.php(114): Twitter->request('https://api.twi...') #1 /var/www/html/sitex/public/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.lib.php(51): Twitter->auth_request('https://api.twi...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/sitex/public/sites/all/modules/twitter/twitter.pages.inc(343): Twitter->get_request_token()
>
> [Abridged]

Having checked out the URL which is generated and sent off by `drupal_http_request` I get the following error message

> Failed to validate oauth signature and token

I have checked the following

- Followed https://drupal.org/node/1346824
- Reinstalled both the Twitter and OAuth modules
- Ensured my OAuth Consumer key is correct
- Ensured my OAuth Consumer secret is correct
- Ensured I have Read & Write permissions
- Ensured my server time is within 5 minutes of Twitter's as per [this thread](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1043#comment-2887)
- Ensured my server is running extension=php_openssl.dll
- Ensured my callback URL is correct - http://mywebsite.com/twitter/oauth

  *Note that I am not on localhost, nor is my host behind .htaccess*

Visiting my callback URL results in the following error at `/admin/config/services/twitter`

> The connection to Twitter failed. Please try again.

- I am not on localhost, but have tried the suggested 127.0.0.1 callback URL regardless.
- I do a version compatible/containing "Patch 5" as mentioned [here](https://drupal.org/node/1924478#comment-7262332)
- I'm using the following versions of the modules

  - Twitter 7.x-6.0-alpha2+1-dev (But have tried 7.x-5.8 too)
  - OAuth 7.x-3.1
  - Core 7.22

I haven't enabled the following- Do I need to?

- OAuth Provider UI
- Twitter actions
- Twitter Post
- Twitter Signin

I'd appreciate it if anyoneis able to provide insight!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just started working with no change- I can only assume it was a temporary problem with Twitter at the time.

To some degree a useless answer, but the question gives others a list of things to try in the same situation and allows me to mark this question as resolved.